# How to use membershipProvider or usernamePasswordvalidator to create a user through WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, membership-provider

I have a WPF application that connects to a WCF service. I need users to be authenticated to call any method of my service but I also need users to be able to register if thy don't have an account.

I first thought about using a usernamePasswordvaldator but I couldn't find a way to create a register method that doesn't go through the validate method of my validator class.

I then saw MembershipPorvider but didn't find any example that matches my case.

Comment: Just have one method that is validated where you pass a userID and passWord.

Comment: Yes but what I'm looking for is a method to create a new user that isn't already in database

Comment: I meant method not validated

Answer (score 0):

You can create a special user in the database. Add this user to a special membership role.
This special user can **only** create new users, it doesn't have any other permissions to the service methods.

You should add a PriciplePermission attirbute on all of your methods, and allow your new role (CreateUserRole) to access just the CreateUser method.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "CreateUserRole")]
public void CreateUser(string username, string password)
```

All other methods should have different roles:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "ADMINISTRATORS")]
public bool DeleteUser(string username)
```

so that this special user can only access the CreateUser method.